# Need help identifying resistors to use as a substitute for my OTG cord project

Tags: resistors, identification, substitution, otg

I'm trying to put together an OTG type C to USB cord and I don't have the required 5.1 kilo-ohm; resistor but I have these. Can I use one or a combination of 2 or 3 to accomplish my goal?

[image: 2k2]

[image: 10]
[image: 33]

[image: 220]

[image: 4R7]

[image: 100]

[image: 1k]

Comment: "I have these"... you have what? You can get 5.1 Ω resistors for less than 0.2¢ each on Digikey (in quantity); why not just buy one?

Comment: And most likely you said the resistor value wrong as kilo-ohms would make more sense than ohms.

Comment: You show two brown-black-black ones. (Three, even.)

Comment: I wouldn't blame anyone for not understanding the horrible, dysfunctional color coding system for through-hole resistors. But if you intend to dabble with electronics you should as a bare minimum have a multimeter and know about series and parallel resistances... after which you could answer this yourself.

Comment: With the idea to "teach a man to fish" here are two links where you can learn resistor color codes and another to learn series and parallel resistor combinations.   Resistor Color Codes:  https://www.arrow.com/en/research-and-events/articles/resistor-color-code ...  Series and Parallel Resistors: https://makeabilitylab.github.io/physcomp/electronics/series-parallel.html

Comment: Mr YOUKNOW - Hi, I don't have time to get more involved but just briefly, based on their shape and their original location on the PCBs, I strongly suspect that while *some* of those components are resistors, *some* of them are axial *inductors* whose markings show their *inductance*. Although not identical in specification to yours, here is an [example datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/3481/A700000006416121.pdf) of a physically-similar type of axial leaded inductor - see how similar they look to a leaded (through-hole) resistor? Sorry to complicate things for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are in the same situation/location as I, being said, the 99% are oblivious to the difficulties, hence the " why not just buy it???!!" And so forth.so seeing how you have the same chargers, adapters and circuit boards as I do, iv learned the most common place to get the resistors we need for both, whether for micro USB to micro, A, C, lightning, or type C to type C, Micro A, B or C. Is most tablet or battery charger's that have a light on them. Universal adapters and phone chargers with the 4.7, 5.1 or even 5.3k resistors all work for both and they are the resistance used for lights in adapters.

Comment: The OP asked if any of the depicted components can be used. Your answer doesn't really address the question.